# Dealing with empty parameters in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-modeler, parameters

I'm building a graphic modeler in QGIS.

I need to model adding multiple fields/columns to a layer and then importing values from other fields/columns into those new fields.

Example :

```
Existing field = a
New field = A
Formula = A = a
```

This works fine.

I'm using user parameter to choose which field to use for the data. In the Field calculator, I specify that

```
Newfield = @Datafield (parameter)
```

The thing is, if the `@Datafield` is non-existent (not selected by the user) the graphic modeler won't run.

What I need is a way make my Field calculator understand that
if `@Datafield` is empty or non-existent (nothing inserted in the userparameter), to insert `NULL` values in the new field, else return `@Datafield` (the values in the Datafield inserted in the parameter).

Comment: I can't reproduce your behavior. Please, include detailed steps to recreate your model.